# In Keycloak, Is there a way to access user roles in a theme?

Tags: jboss, single-sign-on, keycloak

I've built a custom KeyCloak theme, and I'd like to add a menu based on the logged-in users' realmRoles.

I haven't been able to figure out how to access roles from within the .ftl files, and documentation seems non-existent.

Ideally, I'd be able to access them like this (within the .ftl file)

```
<#list user.realmRoles as roles>
... do something with roles
</#list>
```

I expect there's an easy way to get a handle on this, but I haven't been able to find it in the docs.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Any news on this? We have the same problem